# How to evaluate an expression present within string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, expression

Here I need to evaluate an expression present within string.

for eg,

```
>> a = '5 + 6'

>> a = 5 + 6
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `eval` method by passing an *expression* as argument. The *expression* argument is `parsed` and evaluated as a Python expression.

```
a = eval('5 + 6')
```

Comment: Any provisos about safety?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval()` as it treats string as code.

> > a = '5 + 6'
> >
> > eval(a)